# How can I create a nested loop with an increment?

Tags: python-3.x, nested-loops

What I mean is a nested loop that will print out symbols. The number of symbols should be determined by incrementing the rows.
At the same time the column of symbols should run for a set number before moving to the next number.

The outcome will look something like below.

@

@

@@

@@

@@@

@@@

and so on.

I only managed to write this:

```
rows = 5

# Outer loop

symbol = "@"

for i in range(rows):

    # Nested loop
    for j in range(i):
        print(symbol, end=' ')

        print('')
        rows = 5
```

I tried this:

```
rows = 2

# Outer loop

symbol = "@"

for i in range(rows):

    # Nested loop

    for j in range(i):

        print(symbol, end=' ')

        print('')
        rows = 2
```

I was expecting output like:

@

@

@@

@@

@@@

@@@

Comment: It ***** ***wouldn't even have compiled*** ***** in the original posted form. Can you [make it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71626532/edit) identical to the actual source code (that is, with the same indentation)? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
n = int(input())

for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        print("@"*i)
```

**Output:**

[image]

I think you want as many as `n` repeat `@`. So this is:

```
n = int(input())

for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,n+1):
        print("@"*i)
```

**Output:**

[image]

This is a Matrix and you should play with it. It could be `n*n` or `n*m` means `2 * 2` or `2*3` or...

For example, this is `n+1 * n`:

```
n = int(input())

for i in range(1,n+2):
    for j in range(1,n+1):
        print("@"*i)
```

[image]

Comment: Parisa.H.R, you code is so close to what I want. It works the way I wanted it except that, it prints the '@' in a way of defining the value of the number eg.. 1 =@, 2=@@ ,3=@@@.  Is there a way to make the '@' repeat for a specific value before moving to the next line?.. eg. I want it to repeat 3 times..  like single '@' will print 3 times before double '@' will print 3 times and so on. Thanks

Comment: @edah , this is like a matrix you should say that your matrix is `n*m` or `n*n`. I get n from input and in for loop, I create that matrix. If you want a `2*3` matrix you need to get **two** initial inputs from the user. but the base of `nested loop ` is like what I said.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71626704/edit). It covers answers as well.

Comment: @PeterMortensen , `I added the code for copied and pasted` and those images just for showing the output for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

[Thanks very much, parisa-h-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71626532/how-can-i-create-a-nested-loop-with-an-increment/71626704#71626704).

I added a separate input for the outer loop from the code you provided and it worked.

```
n = int(input("This is the row: "))
m = int(input("This is the column: "))
for i in range(n +1):
    for j in range(m):
        print("@"*i)
```

**The output:**

[image]

Comment: your welcome, now you understand how should create Matrix with `nested for loop`.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71630796/edit). It covers answers as well.